# Publish custom files with Visual Studio22 even in singlefile mode

Tags: visual-studio-2022, publish, .net-core-publishsinglefile

I know that i can include additional files in the publish step using this

`<ResolvedFileToPublish Include="..\ReadMe2.md"> <RelativePath>wwwroot\ReadMe2.md</RelativePath> </ResolvedFileToPublish>`

in the publish profile xml

The problem is, that if I select file publish options --> "single file" there is no additional file in the publish folder.
Is there a way to still include additional custom files even when using single file publish options?
Thanks for any hints!